# What Should I download when customizing bootstrap for using accordion?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to customize a bootstrap download for use on WordPress. I have successfully done this for using Modal. I'm having trouble figuring out what boxes I need to check to get everything necessary for using the accordion feature to work properly.
So I need Modal and accordion.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/

I've tried: 
Under JavaScript components:
Component animations (for JS)(includes Collapse) AND Modal

Under jQuery Plugins > Linked to components >
Modals

and under jQuery Plugins > Magic >
Collapse and Transitions

What is happening now is that the accordion content is not hidden (even when the div is not expanded)

The code I'm trying is taken directly from the example found here under accordion example:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/

```
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Item One Content. Item One Content. Item One Content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Item Two Content. Item Two Content. Item Two Content.
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h2 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Item Three Content. Item Three Content. Item Three Content.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result

[image]

Comment: So you're still using version 3? Or you've switched to version 4 and don't know what to do?

Comment: @DavidLiang this is my first time using it. It's version 4. Modals are working correctly, accordions are not. (the links open and collapse but the accordion content is always visible behind the links) I was just wondering if there is something else I should be downloading in addition to what I already downloaded.

Comment: do you have code to show how you use the accordion? Or is that a wordpress plugin written by somebody else?

Comment: @DavidLiang I updated the post with the code and a screenshot.

Comment: It's just CSS that is missing. Basically all the CSS for .card I've got it figured out. @DavidLiang thank you for taking the time to respond to me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your HTML code with the following.

```html
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
         <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
         <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
         </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
         <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```